# How to use an 'input' variable in another script?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to use an input (a 'character name' for a little text game I'm writing to help myself learn Python).

Is it possible to have a user (player's) input, of their name, as a global (or similar) variable within other scripts?

For context, I've made separate tabs/scripts for each "quest" and I would like to transfer the "character name" that was input in the "intro" of the game, across multiple other quest scripts within the same project. without the user having to enter their name each "quest", also, I would need this variable to be written over each time the script starts, so the characters name can change each time the "game" runs.

I've been reading a lot of other answered questions but most refer to adding a variable that Isn't "editable" to a global directory, but haven't been able to find an answer for a variable that can be changed or amended each time the "game" has been initiated.

Also, if possible, could I have a long winded explanation of the process to achieve this? I would like to learn rather than just copy and paste the answer to achieve the result.

For info:

```
character_name = input("What can I call you? he asks excitedly! ")

print(f'''\nPleased to meet you {character_name}.
```

This is the line of code that I've used to let the user input and create the variable `character_name`.

Comment: Don't run them as separate scripts. Import them as modules so you can pass the input as a parameter to the functions.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, I believe i used the wrong term by saying "script" im running them as modules i.e .py files. 
Running it in a module still seems to create errors as the imported module doesn't let me import the "players name" from the intro module as it is a user inputted variable.
I've obviously been able to import other information between modules, but not with a "input changeable variable"   Feels like a chicken and the egg situation.

Comment: if you get error then show full error message in question (not in comment) as text (not image)

Comment: maybe put code in function in module and use `return character_name` in this function and later use `player_name = module.function()`

Comment: your example code has mistake - you forgot `''')` at the end.

Comment: Thank you, yep sorry @furas there were a few more lines below that example, ending with ''') 
I'll give your advice a go! ty

Comment: Modules usually contain function and classes with methods, both of which generally accept arguments that determine what they do — so that's how to pass the name to them.

Comment: a small advice - if there is some data that should be "remembered" or passed around, it should be stored somewhere - usually its a db but here you can simply write two  functions, one to save the players name to a file and another one to obtain players name from this file